# Multiple subdomains with lets encrypt

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have an attractive message indicating me that it is unfortunately not possible to generate a certificate for multiple subdomains:

```
Wildcard domains are not supported: *.mynewsiteweb.com
```

On the other hand it would be possible to generate it one by one for each subdomain.

Is there a better solution? Thank you :)

---

### Edit

Now Certbot supports the Wildcard since 0.22.0 version *(2018-03-07)*

#### Links

- Automatic script: https://certbot.eff.org
- Documentation: https://certbot.eff.org/docs

#### Thanks

- Certbot ❤
- [Jahid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744681/jahid)
- [Ozzy Tashtepe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9155658/ozzy-tashtepe)
- [trojan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838098/trojan)
- [Jay Riley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2177974/jay-riley)

Comment: https://itbru.ru/index.php/2019/03/22/lets-encrypt-wildcard/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Prior to support for wildcards I found it necessary to explicitly list each domain on a certificate in the form

```
… -d example.com -d www.example.com -d blog.example.com -d www.blog.example.com …
```

(which due to complexities in the odd mix of redirected domains I'm using worked best with the --webroot authentication).

Thanks to Trojan's explanation and documentation here:

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html?highlight=wildcard

I was able to generate wildcard certs that are live now. Unfortunately there is not a plugin for EasyDNS.com yet, so I had to perform manual validation (Where Trojans example saved the day). With this approach I was able to generate a certificate in the form

```
… -d *.example.com -d example.com -d *.blog.example.com …
```

Since (for example's sake) blog.example.com was already covered by the *.example.com wildcard, I only had to add the wildcard for *.blog.example.com. In fact certbot would not allow redundancy (complained if I tried to include both *.example.com and www.example.com).

Currently available plug-ins are listed here:

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins

As of this writing they include these DNS providers:

- certbot-dns-cloudflare
- certbot-dns-cloudxns
- certbot-dns-digitalocean
- certbot-dns-dnsimple
- certbot-dns-dnsmadeeasy
- certbot-dns-google
- certbot-dns-luadns
- certbot-dns-nsone
- certbot-dns-rfc2136
- certbot-dns-route53

Perhaps I'll take a peek over the weekend and see how hard it is to write a plug-in for my own DNS provider.

Comment: I had a few subdomains to add, and the first example worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 10):

> it is unfortunately not possible to generate a certificate for multiple subdomains

**Not true**. It **is** possible to generate a cert for multiple sub-domains. Just include those subdomains in the configuration file by their names:

```
domains = example.org, www.example.org, sub.example.org, www.sub.example.org
```

Then run certbot with the configuration file:

```
certbot-auto -c config.ini
```

You will have to verify ownership for each domain.

[See more about configuration file.](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#configuration-file)

Comment: Is there a way to get a certificate for a wildcard subdomain i.e. *.mydomain.com which will work for all subdomain that i put it.

Comment: @vinit : Last time I checked wildcard domain isn't supported by letsencrypt

Comment: Yeah, i also checked on their community forum. This questions was responded negatively 1 month back. I wonder if we can do anything to help.

Comment: @vinit - https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html

Answer (score 9):

**Wildcard domains are now supported by certbot (from ver. 0.22)**

Domain will have to be validated via DNS (you will have to add ***_acme-challenge.yourdomain.tld*** TXT record to your DNS entry with random generated value)

Example:

```
certbot-auto --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d *.example.pl --manual --preferred-challenges dns-01 certonly
```

Answer (score 8):

I just went through the process of generating a single Let's Encrypt certificate for multiple subdomains.  There were some minor challenges that I encountered and resolved.  I posted a short article in the link below explaining the leasons learned I gained when installing Let's Encrypt digital certificates on my Apache web server which provides HTTP and HTTPS access to multiple subdomains.

My most important "lesson learned" is that you need to create a VirtualHost for the HTTP access AND a VirtualHost for each subdomain accessible via HTTPS.  **IMPORTANT:** Each VirtualHost definition must be specified in a single configuration file. The Let's Encrypt certbot will not operate correctly if multiple VirtualHosts are defined within a single configuration file. I defined three (3) VirtualHosts in three (3) different configuration files below. The dummy.conf file serves no functional purpose within Apache (i.e., it will not cause an unnecessary 999 listening port), but it is absolutely necessary for digital certificates to be successfully generated by the Let's Encrypt certbot.

[image: Web Server Conf Files]

Then you can run the following command to generate the certificate:

```
certbot certonly -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

https://www.hueyise.com/index.php/letsencrypt

Comment: Think's, but your link return : ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: @ChrisHuey Welcome to SO. This looks like a great answer, but could be improved by copying the salient points into your answer. This helps prevent link rot, so that the answer is still good even if the site is down. It's fine to still leave the link to your original source though! :)

Comment: Separate file for https and http or separate file for each domain? Can someone validate the port 999s necessity

Answer (score 2):

Lets Encrypt SSL Wildcard/multiple subdomain support will be available starting from February 27, 2018 officially.

> We introduced a public test API endpoint for the ACME v2 protocol and
>   wildcard support on January 4, 2018. ACME v2 and wildcard support will
>   be fully available on **February 27, 2018**

*Source: https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html*